# stackoverflow with dllimport from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, stack-overflow, dllimport

**Scenario**

I made a Wrapper class for a C dll so I can call its functions from managed code and I can access them from a c# WCF Service. Everyting seems fine, but when allocating a lot of memory in the C library. IIS does not seems to like it. It will give me a stackoverflow exception.

**Question**

When allocating memory in the C dll. It breaks in IIS.

```
char    stmt[163840+1]; // allocation a lot of memory
char    stmt2[163840+1]; // allocation a lot of memory
```

Does IIS have special setting to allow more memory to be allocated from the C module?

**Code which expose C dll functions**

Steps:

```
 1. use SetDllDirectory
 2. LoadLibrary
 3. then call my function with DLLImport
 4. FreeLibrary
```

The NativeClassWrapper code (Simplefied)

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static class NativeClassWrapper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    [DllImport("myCDll.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MyFunction(
    );
}
```

C code

```
long MyFunction () {
    char    stmt[163840+1]; // allocation alot of memory
    char    stmt2[163840+1];
    long lReturn = 0L;
    *stmt = '\0';
    *stmt2 = '\0';
    return lReturn;
}
```

Comment: why the minus on the question

Comment: Clearly there's a defect in your code. You didn't show any of the important code. You'll therefore have to debug it yourself. If you want help, provide a [mcve] and diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks David, I updated the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char    stmt[163840+1]; // allocation alot of memory
char    stmt2[163840+1];
```

These allocations are responsible for the stack overflow. You are attempting to allocate large arrays on the stack, and the stack is not large enough. The default stack for a Windows application is 1MB. The arrays on their own will not overflow such a stack. However, it's quite plausible that IIS uses smaller stacks, or that there is not code that you have not shown that makes similar large stack allocations.

If you really need to allocate such large arrays, you'll should do so on the heap.

Comment: Is there anyway to allow IIS to allocate this memory? (Actualy there ar more arrays that allocate memory on the stack of size 16384 and not 2 thats allocate 163840, but for the example it was fitting.)

Comment: Quite probably. Do bear in mind that I don't know what you are trying to achieve, and am not in a good place to advise you on how to write the rest of your program. I'm just answering the question that you asked. I'm explaining why you have a stack overflow error.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. A collega refered me to this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/932909 Where IIS claims 256Kb per thread. I am afraid my dll needs more. So as solution i  will wrap my c dll with a Thread that claims more memory to the stack. I will keep you posted

Comment: No, don't do that. Allocate on the heap.

Comment: I would do like you suggested, but this requires do adjust a lot of code and testing. Which I would do in the future. For now I will adjust the Stack size to 1Mb. This is  sufficient for my needs and is "only" 4 times more then the default.

Answer (score 0):

thanks David Heffernan for youre response. I accpet his answer because it helped me to this solution. The solution I choose was to Start the process that communicates with the C Dll on a different thread and allocate the stacksize to 1MB instead of the default 256KB

```
public void StartNewThread()
{
    const int stacksize = 1024*1024; // 1MB
    var thread = new Thread(NativeDllProcess, stacksize);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(); // Wait till thread is ready

    // .. rest of code here
}

private void NativeDllProcess(object info)
{
    // ..... Code thats calls C dll functions
}
```

More information here : 
[maximum / default stack size IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/932909)

By default, the maximum stack size of a thread that is created in a native IIS process is 256 KB
 Email
 Print
SUMMARY
By default, the maximum stack size of a thread that is created by a native Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) process is 256 KB prior to Windows Server 2008. For example, when Inetinfo.exe, DLLHost.exe, or W3wp.exe creates a thread in IIS 5.0 or IIS 6.0, the maximum stack size of the thread is 256 KB by default. You can also explicitly call the CreateThread function to specify the stack size of the thread. In Microsoft Windows 2000, if the Microsoft ASP.NET Worker Process (ASPNet_wp.exe) creates a thread, the maximum stack size of the thread is 1 MB. In Windows Server 2008 and higher, the maximum stack size of a thread running on 32-bit version of IIS is 256 KB, and on an x64 server is 512 KB.

NOTE: Internet Information Services is a multi-threaded web application platform that allows application code running inside of each worker process to utilize hundreds or more threads at once as necessary. Each thread is bound by the same stack size limit in order to keep the virtual memory usage of the process within manageable limits.